# $http.get giving the html of my index.html in Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, get

This is an odd problem- Sorry in advance for all of the code but I think it will help you understand what I'm attempting.  I have the following in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp"><!--Bootstrap the angular application -->
<head>
  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">  </script><!-- Angular js CDN -->
    <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-  route.min.js"></script><!-- This adds support for ngRoute -->
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script><!--This adds support for ngSanitize and bind html-->
    <script src="mainapp.js"></script><!-- Main angular application file -->
    <script src="scripts/page.js"></script><!--For the Page prototype-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
    <base href="/mainpg/pgBugle/">
    <title>[future title]</title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div><!--This is where our router will place the different   fiews-->

</body>
</html>
```

Then I have this in my mainapp.js

```
(function(){
angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
//config sets up application routing
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/mainpg/pgBugle/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'home'
                })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //this allows urls to not have a     # at the beginning
        })
    //These are some basic controllers I set to test functionality
    .controller('homeCtrl', function(){
        this.name = "<h3>James Allen</h3>";
        })

})();
```

This in my page.js-

```
(function(){
    angular.module('mainApp')
        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/fat', {
                    templateUrl: '/mainpg/pgBugle/templates/page.html',
                    controller: 'pagesCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'pages'
                })})
        .controller('pagesCtrl',['$http', function($http){
            var st = this;
            $http.get('mainpg/pgBugle/api/page.json').success(function(data)    {
                st.datas = data;
        }
        )}]
        );}
    )();
```

This in my page.html-

```
{{pages.datas}}
<div ng-repeat="page in pages.datas track by $index">
    <h3>{{page.pageTitle}}</h3>
    <span>{{page.pageAuthor}}</span>
    <div>{{page.pageBody}}</div>
</div>
```

And this in my page.json

```
[
    {
        "pageId": 1,
        "pageTitle": "A stitch in time",
        "pageBody": "<p>This is some</p><p>Content</p>",
        "pageAuthor": "James"
    },
    {
        "pageId": 2,
        "pageTitle": "Another Time",
        "pageBody": "<p>This is a</p><p>lot of information</p>",
        "pageAuthor": "Mike"
    },
    {
        "pageId": 3,
        "pageTitle": "I like Cheese",
        "pageBody": "<p>Cheese is Really</p><p>Good/p>",
        "pageAuthor": "Mr. Cheese"
    }
]
```

All of the files are in the paths that I have written, for instance the page.json is in a folder called api in the mainpg/pgBugle directories. When I run this application I don't get the contents of the page.json loaded into my variable where I have the $http.get in page.js. I get the contents of the main page's html file and it is displayed where I have {{pages.datas}}. (I put pages.datas in there to try to figure out what was going on since I was just getting a blank screen at first with no errors.)  Any ideas as to why $http would be grabbing the content of the index.html rather than my page.json file?

Comment: what does the server look like?

Comment: I'm using a local apache server- just xampp

Comment: I do have a .htaccess that I'm using to redirect back to the index.html if someone lands on a different path could that be causing it?

Comment: What do you get if you paste `<your-domain-etc>/mainpg/pgBugle/api/page.json` into your browser.  Do you see json?  What are the headers on the request and response?

Comment: I get the contents of the json file

Comment: Have you got the dev console open?  Any errors?  HTML5 mode can be difficult to work with in dev.  Try switching it off and seeing what happens.  Also I noticed that you've missed the leading '/' off the json call.  It probably won't make a difference, but it's worth being consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request a URL which cannot be found, sometimes the default 404 contents will be returned, which is the index.html page in this case. This differs per webserver.

First, make sure that 'mainpg/pgBugle/api/page.json' can be retrieved, ie. by going to that URL via the address bar of the browser.

Comment: You were correct- I disabled my htaccess for a minute and it gave an error that it couldn't find /mainpg/pgBugle/mainpg/pgBugle/api/page.json so it was just giving the index.html because it didn't know what else to do.  So, I just switched my api call to api/page.json and we are up and running! Thank you all